# How to send kwargs arguments via .save() method to a post_save signal?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have two models, Process and Notification and I need to create a notification when a process is saved so Im using a post_save signal for this:

```
def create_notification(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.status in ["ERR", "FIN"] or instance.percent == 100:
        type = kwargs["type"]
        notification = Notification()
        notification.account = instance.owner
        notification.process = instance
        notification.status = "UNREAD"
        notification.content = instance.description
        notification.notification_type = type

        if instance.sub_processes.exists():
            for sub_process in instance.sub_processes.all():
                if sub_process.model_id != "":
                    notification.model_id = sub_process.model_id
                if sub_process.model_name != "":
                    notification.model_name = sub_process.model_name

        notification.save()
```

this is working fine but my problem is that I need to pass an extra argument when I save a process, this argument is for the Notification Object that Im creating, which is `type` so every time im saving a Process object (in a view for example) im trying to do something like this `process.save(type="EMM")` but its not working, the line `type = kwargs["type"]` in create_notification signal isn't doing anything, so how can I send extra arguments to save method ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could work:

```
 # Process model
 def save(self, type=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
    
    self._type = type
    
    return super(Process, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



 # Process post_save
 def create_notification(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
   if instance._type is None:
      return

   if instance.status in ["ERR", "FIN"] or instance.percent == 100:
      type = instance._type
      notification = Notification()
      notification.account = instance.owner
      notification.process = instance
      notification.status = "UNREAD"
      notification.content = instance.description
      notification.notification_type = type

    if instance.sub_processes.exists():
        for sub_process in instance.sub_processes.all():
            if sub_process.model_id != "":
                notification.model_id = sub_process.model_id
            if sub_process.model_name != "":
                notification.model_name = sub_process.model_name

    notification.save()
```